# R: Removing rows from data frame based on external criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, `df.1` and `df.2`, and I'd like to remove rows from `df.2` based on whether certain things about `df.1` are true. Specifically, I want to delete all rows from `df.2` where the `df.1` value of `feistiness` corresponding to the `date` in `df.2` has an `NA` value. How does one go about doing this? (I've looked at other questions and still couldn't figure this out.)

Reproducible code for the first data frame:

```
# create first data frame
dates <- rep(as.Date(5001:5010, origin = "1970-01-01"), times = 4)
dogs <- c(rep("Fido", times = 10), rep("Snoopy", times = 10), rep("Speckles", times = 10), rep("Pit", times = 10))
set.seed(200)
feistiness <- c(round(runif(35, min = 0, max = 100), digits = 0), rep(NA, times = 5))
df.1 <- data.frame(dates, dogs, feistiness)
names(df.1) <- c("date", "dog", "feistiness")
```

Which yields:

```
         date     dog feistiness
1  1983-09-11    Fido         56
2  1983-09-12    Fido         18
3  1983-09-13    Fido         97
4  1983-09-14    Fido         49
5  1983-09-15    Fido         49
6  1983-09-16    Fido         59
7  1983-09-17    Fido         72
8  1983-09-18    Fido         69
9  1983-09-19    Fido         18
10 1983-09-20    Fido         95
11 1983-09-11  Snoopy         69
12 1983-09-12  Snoopy         16
13 1983-09-13  Snoopy         58
14 1983-09-14  Snoopy         65
15 1983-09-15  Snoopy         83
16 1983-09-16  Snoopy          7
17 1983-09-17  Snoopy         12
18 1983-09-18  Snoopy         89
19 1983-09-19  Snoopy         56
20 1983-09-20  Snoopy         52
21 1983-09-11 Speckles         13
22 1983-09-12 Speckles         15
23 1983-09-13 Speckles         16
24 1983-09-14 Speckles         56
25 1983-09-15 Speckles         67
26 1983-09-16 Speckles         15
27 1983-09-17 Speckles         57
28 1983-09-18 Speckles         76
29 1983-09-19 Speckles         57
30 1983-09-20 Speckles         78
31 1983-09-11     Pit         68
32 1983-09-12     Pit         22
33 1983-09-13     Pit         28
34 1983-09-14     Pit          9
35 1983-09-15     Pit         59
36 1983-09-16     Pit         NA
37 1983-09-17     Pit         NA
38 1983-09-18     Pit         NA
39 1983-09-19     Pit         NA
40 1983-09-20     Pit         NA
```

And the second data frame:

```
# create second data frame
dates.2 <- as.Date(c(5002, 5005, 5004, 5009), origin = "1970-01-01")
dogs.2 <- c("Fido", "Snoopy", "Speckles", "Pit")
df.2 <- data.frame(dates.2, dogs.2)
names(df.2) <- c("date", "dog")
```

Which yields:

```
        date      dog
1 1983-09-12     Fido
2 1983-09-15   Snoopy
3 1983-09-14 Speckles
4 1983-09-19      Pit
```

The final output data frame should look the following, with the last row removed because the `feistiness` value for `Pitt` at 1983-09-19 is `NA`:

```
        date      dog
1 1983-09-12     Fido
2 1983-09-15   Snoopy
3 1983-09-14 Speckles
```

Comment: `na.omit(merge(df.2, df.1, by = c('date', 'dog')))` Note that you have a type-o in your `df.1` construction. You wrote "Speckes", should be "Speckles"

Comment: In my version of R (3.4.1) I'm required to supply `origin = 1970-01-01` in the `as.Date` calls to make this reproducible

Comment: Thanks @bouncyball and jayelm - I've fixed those two issues in the post now. bouncyball's solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `anti_join` from `dplyr`. `df_final` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

df_final <- df.2 %>%
  anti_join(df.1 %>% filter(is.na(feistiness)), by = c("date", "dog"))
```